# how to align check boxes in between radio buttons

Tags: radio-button, checkbox

here i am trying to put my checkboxes in between radio buttons, and i also wants to disable those checkboxes if radio button is not clicked.

here how i want--[image]

Vf code--

```
     <table style="width:100%">

        <tr>
            <td align="left"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!contractDateExtend}"/>Contract Start Date</td>
            <td align="left"><apex:inputText value="{!contractDays}" style="width:4%"/>days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!serviceDateExtend}"/>Service Start Date</td>
            <td align="left"><apex:inputText value="{!serviceDays}" style="width:4%"/>days</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="left"> <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!fullDateExtend}"/>Full Revenue Date</td>
            <td align="left"><apex:inputText value="{!fullRevenueDays}" style="width:4%"/>days</td>
        </tr>
      </table>  

         <apex:selectOption itemValue="2" itemLabel="Copy"></apex:selectOption>


     <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!copyCheckbox}"/>Close Date to Contract Start Date

         <apex:selectOption itemValue="3" itemLabel="Manual"></apex:selectOption>
         <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!radioAction}" rerender="pageBlockTableId"/>

      </apex:selectRadio>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the selectRadio attribute  use `layout="pageDirection"`

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!radioItemValue}" layout="pageDirection">
```

**[Doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm)**